# AWS CloudFront not invalidated even after successful execution of `create-invalidation` command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS Cloudfront distribution sitting in front of an S3 bucket that is hosting a static website. Every time I deploy, I invalidate the Cloudfront distro using the AWS CLI using the `create-invalidation --distribution-id $CDN_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"` command which seems to run successfully.

The issue is that it does not seem to invalidate. If I open the production site on Chrome, I'm fed an old version of the site, if I open in an incognito browser with no history I'm served the newest version as I'd expect.

I need some help understanding what some potential could be so I know where to look.

Comment: From your description, your browser is caching the old content -- not CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "index.html" within S3 as your index documents, but are using paths without index.html in them, you need to use the paths without the index.html in them with Cloudfront's invalidate.

So if you have this path on s3:

```
/some/path/index.html
```

And you are accessing this on Cloudfront like this:

```
http://example.com/some/path/
```

Then you will need to do this invalidation:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${YOUR_DIST_ID} --paths /some/path/
```

So basically you need to invalidate the path that the browser would be using, rather than the path that S3 is using.

If you're not using trailing slashes in your URLs then you would probably invalidate without the trailing slashes. Amazon also says if you haven't standardized then you should do both.

So in that case you'd do this:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${YOUR_DIST_ID} --paths /some/path/ /some/path
```

And that would cover both cases in the invalidation.

Comment: While this may make sense, it does not in the context of the OP's question where the OP is invalidating the entire cache: `--paths "/*"`. In the OP's case, it wouldn't matter if `/some/path/` or `/some/path/index.html` were being used, re: the entire cache is being invalidated.